# auto07p IndexError when uses matplotlib 2.0 instead of matplotlib 1.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, index-error

I am recently working on making auto07p work with matplotlib 2.0.

The source code can be found here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/auto-07p/files/auto07p/0.9/

When using matplotlib 2.0 (or any version greater than 1.5), IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. appears:

```
/home/ngb/auto/07p/python/Points.py:1086: VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
  r = rank(array_temp)
Created plot
<graphics.windowPlotter.WindowPlotter2D object at 0x7f9e42007710>
AUTO> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 608, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 370, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/home/ngb/auto/07p/python/graphics/grapher_mpl.py", line 92, in draw
    self.redraw()
  File "/home/ngb/auto/07p/python/graphics/grapher_mpl.py", line 65, in redraw
    FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 351, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1143, in draw
    renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2409, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1136, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 969, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 969, in <listcomp>
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 912, in iter_ticks
    majorLocs = self.major.locator()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 1794, in __call__
    return self.tick_values(vmin, vmax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 1802, in tick_values
    locs = self._raw_ticks(vmin, vmax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 1761, in _raw_ticks
    istep = np.nonzero(steps >= raw_step)[0][0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

It appears that there are only two lines involved. They are from the file /auto/07p/python/graphics/grapher_mpl.py.

The two methods involved are:

```
 def redraw(self):
        # recalculate label positions
        self.grapher.plotlabels()

        FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw(self)
```

And

```
def draw(self):
    ax = self.grapher.ax
    d = {}
    if ax is self.grapher.ax3d:
        [d["minx"], d["maxx"]] = ax.get_xlim3d()
        [d["miny"], d["maxy"]] = ax.get_ylim3d()
        [d["minz"], d["maxz"]] = ax.get_zlim3d()
        d["azimuth"] = ax.azim
        d["elevation"] = ax.elev
        d["cur_lims"] = Axes.get_xlim(ax), Axes.get_ylim(ax)
    else:
        [d["minx"], d["maxx"]] = ax.get_xlim()
        [d["miny"], d["maxy"]] = ax.get_ylim()
    for k in list(d):
        # don't adjust any unchanged settings
        if k == "cur_lims":
            if map(list, d[k]) == map(list, self.grapher._cur_lims):
                del d[k]
        elif d[k] == self.grapher.cget(k):
            del d[k]
    if d != {}:
        if "cur_lims" in d:
            del d["cur_lims"]
        if d != {}:
            self.grapher._configNoDraw(**d)

        self.redraw()
        return
    FigureCanvasTkAgg.draw(self)
```

I would appreciate if anyone can assist me with the error, without changing the matlibplot code but only the auto code. I have read through the code but did not find anything suspicious.

I ran into this error using a given equation and auto file. But if you use matplotlib 2.0 and auto07p to plot most graphs in general, you are very likely to get this error if you zoom on the graph.

I used the files as the following:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArJqyyCr1FQOhkITst8JdVK_mIFV

Put them in auto folder.
Run auto.
and type:

auto("couple2.auto")

Thanks.

Comment: What is the [mcve] of the code that you run to get this error?

Comment: Hey there, I ran into this error using a given equation and auto file. But if you use matplotlib 2.0 and auto07p to plot most graphs in general, you are very likely to get this error if you zoom on the graph.

Comment: So it's only happening when zooming out? My point is that since the error occurs at runtime in the draw method, there is no good way to trace the error back. Instead one needs to debug from a given code, so you would benefit from supplying people with a minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hey there, just uploaded the files. By code do you mean code from auto or my code that auto runs?

Comment: Please try the files from Onedrive and let me know if you can reproduce the error. Please update or set the matplotlib version to 2.0.

Comment: Hey ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it happens when zooming in. It can plot the graph, but the error appears when you zoom in and the graph will remain unchanged and not zoomed in.

Comment: I have problems installing auto07p. So I think I cannot help you here. Since this is a very special problem, you may also try to inquire at the authors of auto07p about it.

Comment: Hey ImportanceOfBeingErnest, did you install all the dependent libraries/ packages required by auto07p? It requires additional libraries such as PLAUT04: SoQt-devel

Comment: http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/auto/auto07p.pdf

Comment: Please check page 14.